# How to find row & column with numpy.where for 2D array

Tags: python, numpy

The code is trying to find the minimum value from a 2D array (measuring distance)

```
dist1 = ma.sqrt(dist2**2+dist3**2)
minimum1 = dist1.min()
```

For a 1D array, I have no problem retrieving the minimum position but not for a 2D array. Trying:

```
imin1, jmin1 = ma.where(dist1 == dist1.min())
```

returns the error:  `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

If the snippet is changed to:

```
imin1 = ma.where(dist1 == dist1.min())
```

It returns a tuple such as `(array([1238, 1238, 1238, ..., 1238, 1238, 1238]), array([   0,    1,    2, ..., 3597, 3598, 3599]), array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]))`
Is there a straightforward way to find the column and row for the minimum (or maximum) value?

Comment: is your `dist` 3d?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [argmin()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html) function to find the minimum index (row/col) of a numpy array. This function returns the index into the flattened array. To get the row and column, you can use [unravel_index()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html):

```py
>>> x = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,0,5],[6,7,8]])
>>> np.unravel_index(np.argmin(x), x.shape)
(1, 1)
```

To find the maximum index, you can use the [argmax()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) instead.